# How to create following styles in wpf?

Tags: wpf, xaml, styles

How do you style the button contents as shown below? For style 1, seems easy to do by using text blocks and Run, but style 2, I'm wondering how to achieve this. 
[image: Style 1]

[image: Style 2]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with `offset`

```
<TextBlock FontSize="72">
    <Run Foreground="Gray" Text="It" /><Run Text="e">
        <Run.Foreground>
            <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,0.5" EndPoint="1,0.5">
                <GradientStop Color="Gray" Offset="0"/>
                <GradientStop Color="Gray" Offset="0.5" />
                <GradientStop Color="Red" Offset="0.5" />
                <GradientStop Color="Red" Offset="1" />
            </LinearGradientBrush>
        </Run.Foreground>
    </Run><Run Text="m" Foreground="Red" /><Run Text=" 1">
        <Run.Foreground>
            <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,0.5" EndPoint="1,0.5">
                <GradientStop Color="Red" Offset="0"/>
                <GradientStop Color="Red" Offset="0.5" />
                <GradientStop Color="Gray" Offset="0.5" />
                <GradientStop Color="Gray" Offset="1" />
            </LinearGradientBrush>
        </Run.Foreground>
    </Run>
</TextBlock>
```

Ref: [Foreground colour of textblock based on position of part of the letter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35682023/foreground-colour-of-textblock-based-on-position-of-part-of-the-letter)